# I have installed the package Microsoft.Graph.Beta in visual studio but can't import it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-graph-api

When i import the package using

```
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;
```

It shows:

> CS0234 the type or namespace Beta does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph' (are you missing an assembly reference)

Proof that i have installed the package correctly..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although the package is called [`Microsoft.Graph.Beta`](http://Microsoft.Graph.Beta), the root namespace of the assembly is `Microsoft.Graph`. The suffix just indicates that it is the *beta* package and not the `Microsoft.Graph` NuGet package. From the [GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet#using-the-beta-client-along-with-the-v10-library) (v1.0 is `Microsoft.Graph`):

> Both the v1.0 and beta Microsoft Graph endpoints share the same namespace.

Consequently, you can use the `Microsoft.Graph` namespace.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
```